# Dynamic array of structs and function call f(const struct_type *const data[])

Tags: c

The following code warns about incompatible type. What is the proper way to solve this code?

thanks

```
typedef struct a_struct struct_type;

void f(const struct_type *const data[], unsigned n);

void test(unsigned n)
{
   struct_type **v;

   assert(n);
   v = malloc(n * sizeof(struct_type *));
   /* fill v with new struct_type (with a malloc per entry) */
   f(v, n); <- WARN on v
}
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the warning on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the compiler is complaining is the first `const` in `f`'s declaration.

Try using

```
void f(struct_type *const data[], unsigned n);
/*...*/
f( v, n );
```

and you won't get the same warning.  Alternatively, you could cast `v` when you call `f`

```
void f(const struct_type *const data[], unsigned n);
/*...*/
f( (const struct_type * const *) v, n );
```

This is a little counterintuitive, but in C, you can't pass a `pointer-to-pointer-to-nonconst` for a `pointer-to-pointer-to-const`.  They made a special exception to allow you to pass a `pointer-to-nonconst` for a `pointer-to-const`.

Here's a FAQ question ["Why can't I pass a `char **` to a function which expects a `const char **`?"](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html):

> You can use a `pointer-to-T` (for any type `T`) where a `pointer-to-const-T` is expected. However, the rule (an explicit exception) which permits slight mismatches in qualified pointer types is not applied recursively, but only at the top level. (`const char **` is `pointer-to-pointer-to-const-char`, and the exception therefore does not apply.)
>
> The reason that you cannot assign a `char **` value to a `const char **` pointer is somewhat obscure. Given that the `const` qualifier exists at all, the compiler would like to help you keep your promises not to modify `const` values. That's why you can assign a `char *` to a `const char *`, but not the other way around: it's clearly safe to *add* `const`-ness to a simple pointer, but it would be dangerous to take it away. However, suppose you performed the following more complicated series of assignments:
>
> ```
> const char c = 'x';     /* 1 */
> char *p1;           /* 2 */
> const char **p2 = &p1;      /* 3 */
> *p2 = &c;           /* 4 */
> *p1 = 'X';          /* 5 */
> ```
>
> In line 3, we assign a `char **` to a `const char **`. (The compiler should complain.) In line 4, we assign a `const char *` to a `const char *`; this is clearly legal. In line 5, we modify what a `char *` points to--this is supposed to be legal. However, p1 ends up pointing to c, which is `const`. This came about in line 4, because *p2 was really p1. This was set up in line 3, which is an assignment of a form that is disallowed, and this is exactly why line 3 is disallowed.
>
> Assigning a `char **` to a `const char **` (as in line 3, and in the original question) is not immediately dangerous. But it sets up a situation in which p2's promise--that the ultimately-pointed-to value won't be modified--cannot be kept.
>
> (C++ has more complicated rules for assigning `const`-qualified pointers which let you make more kinds of assignments without incurring warnings, but still protect against inadvertent attempts to modify `const` values. C++ would still not allow assigning a `char **` to a `const char **`, but it would let you get away with assigning a `char **` to a `const char * const` *.)
>
> In C, if you must assign or pass pointers which have qualifier mismatches at other than the first level of indirection, you must use explicit casts (e.g. (`const char **`) in this case), although as always, the need for such a cast may indicate a deeper problem which the cast doesn't really fix.
>
> References: ISO Sec. 6.1.2.6, Sec. 6.3.16.1, Sec. 6.5.3
>   H&S Sec. 7.9.1 pp. 221-2

Answer (score 0):

Edited based on Rampion's answer.  The problem is with the double const in f()'s declaration.

Code with the warning:

```
struct_type ** v;
v = (struct_type **)malloc(10 * sizeof(struct_type *));      
f(v);
```

This compiles without warning:

```
const struct_type *const* v;
v = (const struct_type **)malloc(10 * sizeof(struct_type *));
f(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this would work for you:

```
f(struct_type *data);

void test(unsigned n)
{
    struct_type *v = malloc(n * sizeof(struct_type *));
    f(v);
}
```

Please let me know how you get on.

Comment: unfortunately, it wont help, because I need to modify it when filling the structs.

Comment: You can still modify it when filling the struct. I recently was struggling with very similar problem and my code looked like:
void clearScrorer(SCORER *scorerArray) {
 scorerArray->name = NULL;
 scorerArray->score = -1;
}
And it worked without any problems. Remember that by doing f(v) you pass the reference to v, so if you modify v inside of f function v elsewhere will be modified as well.

Answer (score -1):

f expects to get as input an array of pointers (const struct_type* []). You pass a pointer to a pointer of struct (const struct_type**).

The best thing to do, IMO, is to change the signature of f to:

```
void f(const struct_type *const* data);
```

Why do you need to pass arrays as arguments to functions?

Comment: Because that's declared like that :) (it's easier in case of static declaration of data[] I guess)

Comment: In C, "void** myvar" and "void* myvar[]" are one and the same.

Comment: sorry, but this is really not a proper answer to the question :) -1 for the sake of sorting the answers

Comment: @Andomar: That's structuring for some people. Sort of :). I just wonder how can I edit it so it will be put on the tail of the list when sorting on response time...