# MinGW GCC 4.7.0 gives me warning passing double [][] to const double(*)[]

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw

I have two type double 2D arrays in main function. I have function that copies array1 to array2. I am passing both arrays to that function. First array doesn't neeed to be changed so I am declaring formal parameter od first array as type const, but MinGW GCC gives ma a warning:

```
main.c:14:5: warning: passing argument 1 of 'Copy' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
main.c:2:6: note: expected 'const double (*)[3]' but argument is of type 'double (*)[3]'
```

Program works besides that warning, but is it OK to declare formal parameter of type const if I only want to read from it. I want to protect actual argument of being alterd.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void Copy( const double (*)[3], double (*)[3], int);

int main(void)
{
    double array[4][3] =
    { 
        {79.2, 12.6, 111.9}, 
        {56.4, 139.2, 111.5}, 
        {11.1, 99.7, 21.0}, 
        {91.0, 11.2, 45.5}
    };
    double arrCopy[4][3];
    Copy(array, arrCopy,  4);


    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%.2f ", *(*(arrCopy + i) + j));
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}

void Copy( const double (*array)[3], double (*arrCopy)[3], int n )
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            *(*(arrCopy + i) + j) = *(*(array + i) + j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove const from

```
void Copy( const double (*array)[3], double (*arrCopy)[3], int n )
```

Comment: yes I no  I can remove const but I heard somewhare that its good to declare formal argumet as const if I only want ot read form array(To protect array content)

Comment: Then declare  double array[4][3] as const.

Comment: Yes, but I dont want to array to be const just want to formal argumet to be const so I cant accidentally change content of array in main function. JUst want to protect him

Comment: Cast it as const when passing it to function.  (const double (*)[3])

Comment: @Armin you never need to cast a non-const to a const

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Ahem..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847772/dynamic-array-of-structs-and-function-call-fconst-struct-type-const-data    Alexey Frunze just posted a excerpt from my link.

Comment: Copy((const) array, arrCopy,  4); ??? gives me main.c:14:5: warning: type defaults to 'int' in type name [enabled by default]
main.c:14:5: warning: passing argument 1 of 'Copy' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
main.c:2:6: note: expected 'const double (*)[3]' but argument is of type 'int'

Comment: @balky read! Copy(  (const double (*)[3]) array, arrCopy,  4);